# Adding Gamma noise to an image without using imnoise function in matlab?

Tags: matlab, histogram, noise, gamma

I have added 6 different type of noise to an image without using imnoise but still there is one type that i couldn't find anywhere, The Gamma noise!!!

how could i add Gamma noise to an image without imnoise??

If you had the answer of the first question, it would be more appreciated if you could give me some advice about how to recognize the type of added noise to an image from its histogram??

One solution that i came up with is to subtract both of the histograms( Original Image and Noisy Image) to find the noise histogram, then recognize it by its distribution function. does this solution work?

Comment: Do you have the stats toolbox?  if you do `randg` http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randg.html or `rndgam` http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gamrnd.html

Comment: Yes, i'm allowed to use rand function, but how? which variables should i choose?

Comment: Also if you don't have the toolbox then this looks useful: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35008-generation-of-random-variates

Comment: Unfortunately no, randg generates gamma values, i have to use rand function and set variables by myself